# Upgrading from Angular 7 to Angular 8, why "ng update" tells me that @angular/cli is not installed?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I try to upgrade my Angular project from version 7 to version 8.
For that I've used the command from the Angular website: `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`

Everything seems to work perfectly without any error, except this warning: 
`Package not installed: "@angular/cli". Skipping.`

And indeed, the `@angular/cli` package stayed at version 7, while all the other packages moved to version 8.

I tried to manually upgrade `@angular/cli`, but this lead to other errors.

`ng v` is giving me this:

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 10.9.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.9
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.9
@angular/http                     7.2.15
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.9
@schematics/angular               7.3.9 (cli-only)
@schematics/update                0.13.9 (cli-only)
rxjs                              6.5.2
typescript                        3.6.2
webpack                           4.29.0
```

What should I do?

Comment: If I upgrade `@angular/cli` manually, I get this error : `An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server`. Then if, as suggested by the error, I update `@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server`, I get the following error when I run ng serve : `Cannot determine versions of "@angular/cli".
This likely means your local installation is broken. Please reinstall your packages.`

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded to have my project working:

1. I've created a new temp project with the lastest angular-cli 8.3.2. : `ng new temp`
2. Then I've replaced all the package references in `package.json` from this new temporary project to my existing project.
3. then I deleted my `node_modules` folder
4. then I ran `npm install`

Comment: Seriously...I'm trying to update an application from 6 to 7, and the directions don't seem to mention how to get all the additional @angular/* packages updated cleanly. I'm feeling very, very dumb but this is not obvious to me.